# How to use OnMyLocationButtonClick with Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I'm new on Android programming, I'm not able to use the MyLocation button on my fragment class which use a collapsingToolbarLayout, i added the Mylocation button with this line of code:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I read the official doc and It said:

> When a user clicks the button, the camera centers the map on the current location of the device, if it is known.

the button appear but in my case nothing happens when i press the button.

Where am I wrong?

this is my Fragment class code:

```
public class MapFrag extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LatLng currentPosition;

//
private List<Place> places;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
//



//imageLoader – our ImageLoader object which we’ll use to download the images
ImageLoader imageLoader;


private GoogleMap googleMap;

private SupportMapFragment map;

private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

private static View rootView;


// with image
private static final String ENDPOINT_PLACE = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }


    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    requestJsonObject();



    imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getImageLoader();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Map");

    toolbarTextAppernce();

    enableMapScrolling();


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}



private void toolbarTextAppernce() {
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapsedappbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expandedappbar);
}


public void setUpMap() {

    if (googleMap == null) {
        map = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);

    }

}

/**
 * This method enable the possibility for the user to scroll the map
 */
private void enableMapScrolling() {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_id).getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
    behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    params.setBehavior(behavior);

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    if (googleMap != null) {


        //noinspection MissingPermission
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);

        addMarkers();

        //where map start
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 15));

    }

}


/**
 * this method add all coordinete point of the json file with a marker to the map
 */
private void addMarkers() {

    for (Place place : places) {

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getCoordinates()).title(place.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                place.getName().substring(1)));
    }

}


private void requestJsonObject() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT_PLACE, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

    //add request to the queue
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}

private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        Log.d("PLACE FRAGMENT", "Response: " + response);
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson jsonPlace = builder.create();
        places = new ArrayList<>();
        places = Arrays.asList(jsonPlace.fromJson(response, Place[].class));

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), places);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setUpMap();

    }
};

private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(rootView, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        requestJsonObject();
                    }
                });

        // Changing message text color
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

        // Changing action button text color
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        snackbar.show();

    }
};


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        currentPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BUTTON CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
}
```

this is my layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

this is the permission in the manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
...
```

this is my build.gradle:

```
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
...
```

Comment: Is googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this); called? Maybe googleMap is null and thus, this line of code is not called. Try to use a breakpoint to debug your code.

Comment: I call it in "onMapReady" method, and i think isn't null because it I'm able to call moveCamera on it.

EDIT 
this is what i see in the debugger: 
 
`this = {PlaceFragment@6434} "PlaceFragment{f7320ff #1 id=0x7f0d007a}"

googleMap = {GoogleMap@6471} 

currentPosition = {LatLng@6909} "lat/lng: (55.xxxxx,9.xxxxxx)"`

Comment: Try to implement the click listener directly where you set the listener:  googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            Toast.makeText(
getActivity(), "BUTTON CLICKED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return true; 
       }
       });

Comment: i just try that but doesn't work. 

it's possible if is an error caused by the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: It seems so. I tried in a sample project and it seems that if it's outside CollapsingToolbarLayout it works, but when I add MapFragment inside CollapsingToolbarLayout the click event is not intercepted anymore.

Comment: In fact, it seems that the Toolbar is the problem. I tried the following scenarios: 1) to remove the toolbar code from xml and let only the MapFragment. In my case, if I removed the toolbar, the click worked. 2) Also if I set a smaller height for the toolbar the click event also worked, which means the toolbar overlaps the location button (in my project in the upper right corner of the screen).

Answer (score 3):

Toolbar overlaps the "my location" button. You can try to add padding "around the edges of the map using the GoogleMap.setPadding() method. The map will continue to fill the entire container, but text and control positioning, map gestures, and camera movements will behave as if it has been placed in a smaller space." ([see Maps Documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding)

```
mMap.setPadding(200, 200, 200, 200);
```

Or you can try to add:

```
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
```

in your xml, for the MapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it changing MyButton position in the onMapReady method with this code:

```
// Get the button 

View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                locationButton.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```